# How to run vb code from main method in ASP.net mvc3 application

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently I am developing web application with ASP.net MVC and VB.net. I want to develop database access object separately. So, I developed CityDao object by using ADO.net. After that, I want to test that CityDao object. So, how can I test that dao object only. Can I test with main method like java code. Or any way to test that dao code sololy.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Test Unit project that references the CityDao object. Then write your unit tests to verify the required functionality.